# Create 64 bit registry key (non-WOW64) from a 32 bit application

Tags: 64-bit, windows-installer, registry, 32-bit, wow64

I have a Visual Studio installer that is creating some registry keys:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\MyApp
```

but the registry keys it is creating are automatically appearing under Wow6432Node:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\MyApp
```

How do I ignore the Wow6432Node when creating registry keys in my C# code being executed by the msi?

Comment: I guess, since your application is 32-bit, Windows make sure that the changes come under the `Wow6432Node`. To get it out of that node and place the entries under normal paths, your application should be 64-bit.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Just FYI, .NET 4.0 supports this natively. Example:

```
RegistryBase = RegistryKey.OpenBaseKey(RegistryHive.LocalMachine, RegistryView.Registry64);
```

You can then use that **RegistryBase** variable to access anything in the 64-bit view of HKLM. Conversely, **Registry32** will let a 64-bit application access the 32-bit view of the registry.

Answer (score 2):

Since there is very little documentation about `OpenBaseKey`, I'll expand on shifuimam's answer and provide a solution for the OP:

```
Private Sub Foo()
    Dim myAppIs64Bit = Environment.Is64BitProcess
    Dim baseKey As RegistryKey
    If (myAppIs64Bit) Then
        baseKey = RegistryKey.OpenBaseKey(RegistryHive.LocalMachine, RegistryView.Registry64)
    Else
        baseKey = RegistryKey.OpenBaseKey(RegistryHive.LocalMachine, RegistryView.Registry32)
    End If
    Dim myAppKey As RegistryKey = baseKey.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\MyApp")
End Sub
```

If the app is 32-bit, `myAppKey` points to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\MyApp`. If 64-bit, it points to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\MyApp`.

The advantage of `OpenBaseKey` is that it eliminates the need to reference `Wow6432` in your code.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/advapi32/regopenkeyex.html.  You'll need to use the registry redirector and pass in the proper value for the access mask.  Unfortunately you'll need pInvoke.

Comment: Oh fantastic. Is there any nice .NET API around that someone has written to wrap the pinvoke calls and make it not so terrible?

Comment: I wouldn't say it's that terrible really. A bit inconvenient perhaps. Just add the DllImports and define KEY_WOW64_64KEY. A more concise example (for deletion) can be found on http://geekswithblogs.net/derekf/archive/2007/06/26/113485.aspx.