# I can't access certain subkeys in an entry in the registry

Tags: c#, windows-7, windows-vista, registry

I'm trying to get to HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\GameUX\, but the only subkey being returned in C# is MachineSettings - even though there are additional subkeys, including Games and several keys named for different user SIDs. How can I access these other keys? Even a standard user account can read the content of both Games and that account's own SID (when looking in regedit)...

Comment: What code are you using? And note that regedit runs as Administrator account (you should get a UAC prompt).

Comment: Right - Running the app within visual C# express or as compiled and "as administrator" still brings about the same problem. The code is:

http://pastebin.com/dEXa1EqD

GameIDs[0], if it was reading the subkeys correctly, would equal Games, not MachineSettings (which is what it is currently).

Comment: Strange, this code works for me (both as admin and as a regular user). I'm on Win7 x64 with no uac... What version of .NET are you on?

Comment: I've discovered it's because I'm using C# Express, which only compiles 32-bit binaries. The GameUX key and subkeys I'm trying to access is in the 64-bit registry hive, which I can't see from a 32-bit application using the built in API for accessing the registry.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So the issue was related to running a 32-bit application in a 64-bit Windows environment. 64-bit Windows sandboxes 32-bit content (which is why there's a C:\Program Files (x86)) in a way that is transparent to applications. 32-bit applications that use the registry access a sandboxed hive inside HKLM\WOW6423Node, which is why I wasn't seeing the expected result when querying a key inside HKLM.

Fortunately, .NET 4.0 (introduced with VS.NET 2010 and its Express Edition counterparts) includes a super easy function that lets a 32-bit application see and use the 64-bit registry (and vice versa).

Answer is here:
[Create 64 bit registry key (non-WOW64) from a 32 bit application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2197086/create-64-bit-registry-key-non-wow64-from-a-32-bit-application/2932606#2932606)

Comment: Spent hours on this one. What function in .NET 4.0?

Comment: Sorry about that! Added a link to the answer.